# Excess space on HTML page

Tags: css, debugging, responsiveness

There's an excess space to the right side of my landing page on mobile view. You can check it out on https://yole-dev.github.io/floorpro.ngpro/

I have checked my CSS to see if I had accidentally set a padding-right or margin-right on the body but I can't find the bug that's causing this issue

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the pictures in your portfolio section (just above the yellow footer) are going out of the right margin of your whole page which is creating excess space on the right side of your landing page. Also, I would like to suggest you give '**margin: auto**' as a CSS property to mostly all of your blocks in order to have proper alignment. Just give the 'margin: auto' property at the beginning of any CSS block.

Comment: Thanks let me try that out, hopefully it works just fine afterwards